# Python Parsing data from site using lxml

Tags: python, parsing, python-2.7, lxml

I'm new to Python. That's why I'm asking help.
I need to parse ssome data from site. I'm using Python 2.7. 
So here's my code:

```
import urllib
import lxml.html

url = 'http://www.pogoda.YANDEX.RU/MOSCOW'
sock = urllib.urlopen(url)
content = sock.read()
pageReady = u'content.decode()'
page = urllib.urlopen('http://pogoda.yandex.ru/moscow/')
xmldata = lxml.html.document_fromstring(pageReady)
temperature = xmldata.xpath('//div[@class="b-thermometer__now"]/text()')              
clouds = xmldata.xpath('//div[@class="b-info-item b-info-item_type_fact-big"]/text()')
sock.close()

print('%s, %s'%(temperature[0], clouds[0]))
```

So I got next message:

```
File "weather.py", line 15, in <module> print('%s, %s'%(temperature[0], clouds[0])) 
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: [Parsing machine-readable xml from `"https://export.yandex.ru/weather-ng/forecasts/{city_id}.xml"`](https://gist.github.com/7733298) might be more robust than parsing html provided for humans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pageReady` contains just `content.decode()` as its content because of following line:

```
pageReady = u'content.decode()'
```

You should use `page.read()` to get content of the web page as follow:

```
import urllib
import lxml.html

# pageReady = u'content.decode()'   <----------- Remove/comment out this line.
page = urllib.urlopen('http://pogoda.yandex.ru/moscow/')
pageReady = page.read()   # <-------------------------------
xmldata = lxml.html.document_fromstring(pageReady)
temperature = xmldata.xpath('//div[@class="b-thermometer__now"]/text()')              
clouds = xmldata.xpath('//div[@class="b-info-item b-info-item_type_fact-big"]/text()')
page.close()

print('%s, %s'%(temperature[0], clouds[0]))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because your `temperature` and `clouds` are empty lists.